# Yii 2 starter kit inside VirtualBox docker toolbox - symlink(): Protocol error

Tags: docker, yii2, virtualbox, docker-toolbox, docker-quickstart-terminal

Yii 2 starter kit inside VirtualBox docker toolbox on Ms Windows -

`symlink(): Protocol error`

when opening the Yii2 starter kit website inside a Docker Toolbox - VirtualBox, following the exact Yii2 starter kit documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact, that VirtualBox and also the quickstart docker toolbox must be run in the Windows administrative mode, in order for the VirtualBox to be able to create symlinks.